# Do I even need a federation certificate?

Tags: exchange-2010, self-signed-certificate, exchange-2016

I'm in the process of migrating our Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2016, which is going smoothly, except for one issue, which I just can't seem to find an answer to.

The 2010 Exchange had an expired Federation certificate, this of course was migrated to the 2016 Exchange automatically. And expectedly both servers are complaining it has expired. However, we don't have a trust with any other organization, so is this even necessary?

If I execute the Powershell command,

> Get-FederatedOrganizationIdentifier | Format-List AccountNamespace,Domains

I seem to get nothing,

> AccountNamespace :
>
> Domains          :

I've read about deleting the Trust and recreating it as I can't renew the certification once it has expired. If nothing else to just shut the server up.

Comment: Nobody has an answer to this??? Seriously?

Maybe it is a bigger problem.

Comment: `Nobody has an answer to this??? Seriously?` - This isn't a help desk. If someone has an answer and they're so inclined to offer it, then they'll do so  in their own time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expired certificate would not function anymore. You can feel free to delete it.

If any service requires such certificate, just issue a new one.